# How to type exceptions in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the following valid typescript code.

```js
try{
    console.log("test");
}catch(error: any){
    console.log(error.message)
}
```

This works just fine but the `error:any` sets off the following eslint error message.

```
error  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
```

Removing the `any` type causes my typescript compiler to throw a different error. What I can do that appeases both the typescript compiler and eslint? I know a simple solution would be to disable that linter rule for that line, but that doesn't seem like it's the best way forward.

Comment: Try the `unknown` type